# Compiling Caffe with Cuda 8.0 on GTX 1080

Tags: caffe

I am using Nvidia GeForce GTX 1080, which requires Cuda 8.0. Nonetheless, from experiments, I find that it works well with Cuda 7.5 but the error appears when my network has a dropout layer. On the other hand, when I use Cuda 8.0, I get the error:

```
./build/tools/caffe: error while loading shared libraries: libcudart.so.7.5: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
```

I assume that the problem may be that I have compiled Caffe with Cuda 7.5 and the following `CUDA_ARCH` parameters.

```
CUDA_ARCH := -gencode arch=compute_20,code=sm_20 \
    -gencode arch=compute_20,code=sm_21 \
    -gencode arch=compute_30,code=sm_30 \
    -gencode arch=compute_35,code=sm_35 \
    -gencode arch=compute_50,code=sm_50 \
    -gencode arch=compute_50,code=compute_50
```

When I use those parameters and try to compile with Cuda 8.0, I get the following error:

```
make: *** No rule to make target `/usr/local/cuda/include/thrust/detail/type_traits/result_of.h', needed by `.build_release/cuda/src/caffe/layers/softmax_layer.o'.  Stop.
```

Do you think this is the problem? If yes, what would be the correct `CUDA_ARCH` parameters for Cuda 8.0 and GTX 1080. If no, what is the problem?

Answer (score 0):

The solution is just:

```
make clean 
make all
```

And I used the following `CUDA_ARCH` parameters:

```
CUDA_ARCH := -gencode arch=compute_20,code=sm_20 \
    -gencode arch=compute_20,code=sm_21 \
    -gencode arch=compute_30,code=sm_30 \
    -gencode arch=compute_35,code=sm_35 \
    -gencode arch=compute_50,code=sm_50 \
    -gencode arch=compute_50,code=compute_50
    -gencode=arch=compute_52,code=sm_52 \
    -gencode=arch=compute_52,code=compute_52 \
    -gencode=arch=compute_60,code=sm_60 \
    -gencode=arch=compute_61,code=sm_61 \
```

Answer (score 0):

You haven't included the correct NVIDIA nvcc sm flags to compile CUDA for the GTX1080 (SM architecture 61).

You should add `-gencode=arch=compute_61,code=sm_61`to your `CUDA_ARCH` parameter and recompile.